# Дан трехмерный массив с числами, как с помощью вложенных циклов найти сумму элементов этого массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Вот что я смог сделать:

```js
let arr = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; i++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < arr[j].length; k++) {
            console.log([i] + [j] + [k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Дальше не знаю.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Двумерный массив понимаю как вывести, а вот трёхмерный нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение суммы с помощью вложенных циклов:

```js
let arr = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]];
let sumArr = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    for ( let k = 0; k < arr[i][j].length; k++) {
      sumArr += arr[i][j][k];
      //console.log([i] + [j] + [k]);
    }
  }
}
console.log('Сумма: ', sumArr)
```

Comment: Спасибо за обьяснения, теперь понял где ошибка и как решать, еще раз СПАСИБО.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]];
const sum = arr.flat(Infinity).flat(Infinity).reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y; });
console.log(sum); // 36
```

Comment: Зачем зачем `flat(Infinity)`?

Comment: @ksa, чтобы до конца сложить многомерные массивы в один и потом суммировать.

Comment: Посмотри мой вариант, почитай описание для `flat()` - вполне хватит и одного такого вызова. ;)

Comment: @ksa, спасибо, не знал